# what is the time complexity of list.index(obj) method?

Tags: python

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
a = list1.index('c')
print(a) #2
```

But what is the time complexity?
is it O(1) or O(n)?

Comment: `O(n)`, assume... just because you need to rescan the list

Comment: Since you are not using a dictionary/hash-table, I think index needs to iterate over the list. So it will be `O(n)`

Comment: This question could be answered using minimal Google skills. Or, just by common sense: it is impossible to be better than O(n), and the obvious naive implementation is O(n), which means that implementing it in a way that is worse than O(n) would require an active effort to deliberately make it slow, which we can assume to be not the case, ergo, it is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity is O(n) . Have a look at the link

http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 0):

It's O(n), also check out: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

> This page documents the time-complexity (aka "Big O" or "Big Oh") of various operations in current CPython. Other Python implementations (or older or still-under development versions of CPython) may have slightly different performance characteristics. However, it is generally safe to assume that they are not slower by more than a factor of O(log n)..